# Yolo or R-CNN for accurate detection

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I am looking for a good object detection in term of accuracy. I found that Yolo is much faster than R-CNN but Yolo has low detection accuracy than R-CNN. Am I right? I just care about detection accuracy, while detection time is not important. Could you suggest to me any method for high detection accuracy? Thanks

Comment: Hi user8264, I didn't vote on this but I would guess that your question got downvoted because it looks too much like a [library recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (specifically "Could you suggest to me any method for high detection accuracy?"), and library recommendations are off topic for this site. You may want to consider editing your question if that wasn't what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask this question in CrossValidated as it does not fit the requirements for StackOverflow.

The answer depends on whether or not you are referring to R-CNN, Fast R-CNN, or Faster R-CNN, and also what neural network model and data set you trained it on.  For example, Faster R-CNN ZF is less accurate than YOLO but Fast R-CNN and Faster R-CNN VGG-16 are more accurate than YOLO.  For more details see slides 14 through 17 of Xavier Giro-i-Nieto [slides](https://www.slideshare.net/xavigiro/you-only-look-once-unified-realtime-object-detection).